# Raphaeljs bubble chart query(Can anyone tell me what chart is this exactly?)

Tags: javascript, charts, raphael, pie-chart, graphael

Can someone please let me know how should I implement this kind of chart? I need to use a javascript library for implementing a chart which has a big circle (100%) inside which there are small semi-circles which divide the bigger circle. Its kind of pie chart but not exaclty pie chart. I want semicircles inside a big circle It looks like a bubble chart to me but it is enclosed within a circle. I am not quite sure which library should I use for this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you're asking for the name of that type of chart, this isn't the place to ask. If you're asking what library you should use, this isn't the place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

write your own.
you can make divs into circles with css(border-radius), even into triangles(3d transform within div dat gives no overflow) if you try hard.
then you could utilise absolute positioning to place them where you want them.
That way you dont even need javascript or a library.

By request:
http://jsfiddle.net/h6su5/

Just a small example what you can do with google and some inventive thinking ;-)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but I am still not clear as to how should I go about this. You mean that i should change the sector's div css?

Comment: hey... thank you very much... your  example is exaclty what I was looking for... but can we do this dynamically... i mean I need to use it as a graph... here I can see only static values. This is plain html and css. Am I right? So how should I make this stuff dynamic so that it could be used to represent data?

Comment: Jup, just plain ole styling.
If you want to make it dynamic, well just read up onto how to change javascript css selectors for width, height etc...
I suggest you start http://javalessons.com/cgi-bin/js/javascript-tutorial.cgi?1cd=css here.
By the way, accepting the answer would be nice ;-)

Comment: so how do I calculate with percentages? I mean...   how shall i calculate value in percentage also how we calculate the position for the each bubble. For Eg: If the whole outer circle is 100%.... and the 3 inner circles are 20%, 70% and 10% each.. how should I represent that?

Comment: Percentages are relative. 1% could be 2px for example, so 50% = 100px, you could use the formula percentage * multiplier = width and height.
Where you wish to place the bubbles is entirely up to you.
If you wish them to remain static, let them be static at one point and have them grow. If you wish them to move, you'll need to think up a formula to make them move up and down, left to right to make them move when the percentage increases or decreases.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it doesnt work that way!! :( Eg: if its 50% which is 100px so.... width and height will be 100px? I will make the position static, but the inner circles should increase/decrease with the increase or decrease of the percentage, but by modifying the height and width is not helping me ... could you suggest me wherer am i going wrong?